# C# Selenium Webdriver - How to find a link by multiple strings while also using an in-string reference?

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I'd like to click a link by two different strings.

I tried the following code below, but it does not seem to be working.

Any help?

```
xPathString = String.Format("//a[contains(text(), 'Enforcement') and contains(text(), '{0}')]", title);
FindElement(By.XPath(xPathString)).Click(); //enforcement inspector
```

The error message I get is:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: By.XPath: //a[contains(text(), 'Enforcement') and contains(text(), 'Inspector')]
```

The href tag for the link is:

```
/.../Enforcement/Inspector
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be checking the `@href` *attribute*, not the text:

```
//a[contains(@href, 'Enforcement') and contains(@href, '{0}')]
```

And, make sure the `title` variable actually has `Inspector` string value.

Comment: Thanks @alecxe. Yes the title variable is a default parameter. I appreciate the help. :)

Answer (score 1):

other way to do it is:

```
FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(text(), 'Enforcement') and contains(text(), '" + title + "')]")).Click(); //enforcement inspector
```